# If word in column A starts with letters in column B then in SQL

Tags: sql

My database Elements have som inputs.

**COLUMN A**
Name: 
Helium
Lithium

**COLUMN B**
Symbol: 
He
Li

If Name starts with symbols in column B, then 'Yes' should be printing in a new column C.
Else 'No'

Not sure how to write in SQL

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the database you are using

Comment: Hi, I have already tagged with sql.

Comment: SQL is not a database it is a language. Databases are things like Oracle, Snowflake, Postgres, MySql, etc. Each database supports its own version of SQL so without knowing which database you are using it is not possible to be sure that the SQL code anyone suggests will actually work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, (Case When SUBSTRING (ColumnA, 1, 2) = ColumnB Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End) as ColumnC from Elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these two columns belong to the same table and that the values are stored on the same row, you can use `like` and a `case` expression:

```
select e.*, 
    case when columna like concat(columnb, '%') then 'Yes' else 'No' end as columnc
from elements e
```

The actual function to concatenate strings varies across databases. `concat()` is quite widely supported; the standard operator is `||`, so `columnb || '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from b where a.col like b.col || '%')
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as flag
from a;
```

Note:  `||` is the standard operator for string concatenation.  Your database may not support the operator, but it would have a similar function or operator.